# Accessing my init.m from another machine?

Tags: configuration

I have stored my `init.m` as `CloudObject["init.m"]`.

What I'd like to do is load it (that is, all of its symbol and function definitions) onto another Wolfram machine.  I have tried

```
CloudGet[CloudObject["init.m"]]
```

but it doesn't work.  What is the way to do this?

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean here?

Comment: ktm: My symbol definitions from init.m don't seem to load.  Perhaps my question could be better asked as: what is the proper way to (i) upload symbol definitions to a cloud object called "init.m" and (ii) retrieve those symbol definitions on another machine?

Answer (score 1):

```
  initURL = CloudExport["$myStart = 42;", "Text", "init.m", Permissions -> "Public"]
```

and then

```
CloudImport[initURL , "Package"]
```

will evalaute `$myStart` to `42`